# Router is unable to renew dynamic IP

Tags: networking, router, ip, dynamic-ip

Like 2 years ago I was checking out the browser settings and decided to switch to a static IP, as I wanted to use this network as a server, and if the external IP constantly changed, it would be very difficult to update it everywhere. Now I found that was a mistake and decided to change it back, but I couldn't get a new dynamic IP. It tried to connect, but failed and set all of the IPs to 0.0.0.0. I could swap back to using a static IP.

Is there any way I can fix this? The TP-Link setup shows that using a dynamic IP is available, but it doesn't work.

Edit: The router model is TL-WR841N (with `0.9.1 4.16 v0001.0 Build 180319 Rel.57291n` version firmware)

Comment: Are you able to do a complete hardware reset of the router? That should fix the issue.

Comment: @John Is resetting it the only solution? I don't want to lose all settings and data on the device.

Comment: Get your settings on the Router Setup page. Most routers do not have too many settings.

Comment: What OS? Please post the relevant router settings.  I am also confused that your browser settings determine the IP address of your machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RadoslavL You're in the right place, but try to configure it as dynamic again. You may have to reboot your router **and**/or the ISP's device before it will get a response. Your ISP may only allow specific MAC addresses to get an IP, so if you enabled "Clone MAC address" at some point, then you could have trouble. I recommend contacting the ISP, since they should have basic instructions for their required router settings

Comment: @RohitGupta The OS doesn't matter, as this is all in the router settings.

Comment: Did you get the static IP from your ISP? What model is the router? What is the settings page? Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777958/edit) your post with additional information.

Comment: Are you connecting the WAN port to a modem of some kind? If yes, check why the that one isn't providing IP address. If you're connecting directly to your ISP, firstly reset the router, then ensure WAN Connection is set to Dynamic and finally plug it in. If it's not getting an IP from the ISP, contact them.